# Is it wise to place .css and .js files on a CDN?

Tags: compression, cdn, pagespeed

It seems like most people use a CDN for placing images and/or videos.  Is it wise to place your js and css on a cdn as well?

Answer (score 3):

I believe so.  However, if either is dynamically generated you will want to place a relatively low ttl (time to live) on the files so the CDN knows to pull fresh copies.  However, if they are not, I would think that dumping them onto Amazon's S3 would be fine.

One caveat - make sure you have an easy way to test and develop without using the CDN as cacheing can be a headache during this process.

[edit]
After some more experience, I believe it's best to version these files and then update their references w/i whatever generates the views.

For example:

style.20111112.css
shoppingcart.20111113.js

This clears the need to have super low ttl's and purge the CDN of the cached copies.

Answer (score 3):

While it's a good idea in principle, **always have a backup**.

With Javascript, if the CDN goes down or the client can't access that js for some reason, then having a local copy as backup will keep your site flexible.

For example, with jQuery, you can have the best of both worlds with this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

[source and more info](http://www.frederikvig.com/2010/04/backup-plan-when-loading-the-jquery-library-from-cdn/)

Comment: is this still relevent today or are there newer techniques? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes but... before you place the CSS and JS on a CDN

Merge any separate CSS files and minimise them - the browser won't start rendering the page until they're all downloaded.

Work out which JS files you need for the page to download and which ones can be downloaded later, then place the ones needed in the header, and the others at the foot of the page or load them asyncronously (don't forget to minify them too)

A CDN gives you a couple of wins

1. Reduced latency
2. Extra hostnames to download from
3. If you use it right a cookieless domain for static content.

There's some real world examples on the performance of different optimisations in this presentation that was doing the rounds the other day - https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=0ASIJhpwrlBx6ZHA5emJmcF81MmM5Zzk3NmM0&authkey=COe29aAD&hl=en_GB (it's not mine)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with it (especially for javascript if you have multiple websites using the same javascript code).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are written from people without CDN experience.

If you use Akamai or one of the other large CDN providers you'll find that CDNs hit your site for the content (thus you don't "backup" your data), and then cache the data until you invalidate it.

A CDN like Akamai will make a huge difference -- unless you have edge servers distributed around the globe.  Some of our customers in Germany went from 15 second page load times to less than 3 seconds.

I suggest reading the benefits section of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to learn more.